# Inspiration for Ulysses 31?

Tags: cartoon, inspiration, ulysses-31

What surprised me most about [Ulysses 31](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_31) was its use of [Greek mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_mythology) in a futuristic setting. For example, the protagonists encountered [Zeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeus) (amongst other mythological characters):

[image]

What inspired the writers to put these two apparently contradictory elements (ancient mythology and a sci-fi future)<sup>1</sup> together?

<sub>1 For the record, I think this combination was *genius*.</sub>

Comment: Other than it is a retelling of the Odysseus (Ulysses) tales from Greek mythology?